# Sorting in Linq by constructing the linq statement as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, sorting

The user have the option to sort by price or by date listed. Both can be sorted in ascending or descending. They both can be used or one of them.

What is the best practical method to use in such a situation ?

Can I make 1 linq statement and replace the words "ascending"/"descending"  or remove them from the statement by modifying a string ? (in other words, construct the linq statement like sql?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on strings, you can use the [SortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum:

```
public MyCollection OrderedByPrice(SortOrder sortOrder)
{
     if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
     {
         return new MyCollection(this.OrderBy(x => x.Price));
     }
     else
     {
         return new MyCollection(this.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price));
     }
}
```

As per your comments, if you want to order by both you could use [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public MyCollection OrderedByPriceThenByDate(SortOrder sortOrder)
{
     if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
     {
         return new MyCollection(this.OrderBy(x => x.Price)
                                .ThenBy(y => y.Date));
     }
     else
     {
         return new MyCollection(this.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price)
                                .ThenByDescending(y => y.Date));
     }
}
```

Comment: So if i want it sorted by both, I need to call  OrderedByPrice and its result sent to Order By Date ?

Answer (score 1):

you can also build an expression to do it

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSort<T>(
   IQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, SortOrder sortOrder)
{
     if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
     {
         return src.OrderBy(predicate));
     }
     else
     {
         return src..OrderByDescending(predicate));
     }
}

ExecuteSort(src, v => v.Price, ortOrder.Ascending);
```